# Suggestion to search algorithm that runs in Θ(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

Let A[0..n − 1] be an array of distinct integers. The integer with rank k in A is the k’th largest integer among the integers in A. The median of A is the integer in A with rank b(n − 1)/2c. How might an algorithm look, that given a k finds the integer with rank k in A in Θ(n) time?

Comment: What is `b` and `c`?

Comment: You probably want quicksort's partition function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are searching for is called [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). It is a randomised algorithm and it works in expected *O*(*n*) time on an array consisting of *n* elements.

[A worse-case *O*(*n*) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Rivest_algorithm) also exists, but it is only of theoretical interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compromise the time from Θ(n) to Θ(K*log(K)) - "K" stands for K largest integer. Then have a look of MaxHeap sort. When "K" is small, it will be close to Θ(n) but definitely will be bigger when dealing with median.